# "ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty" when running 'cdk deploy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have this error when I run `cdk deploy`. How can I know what causes this?

```
node:internal/fs/rimraf:202
      throw err;
      ^

Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '\\?\C:\Users\ro\AppData\Local\Temp\jsii-kernel-WYBhQW\node_modules\@aws-cdk\asset-kubectl-v20\layer'
    at Object.rmdirSync (node:fs:1229:10)
    at _rmdirSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:260:21)
    at rimrafSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:193:7)
    at node:internal/fs/rimraf:253:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _rmdirSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:250:7)
    at rimrafSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:193:7)
    at node:internal/fs/rimraf:253:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at _rmdirSync (node:internal/fs/rimraf:250:7) {
  errno: -4051,
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
  path: '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\ro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jsii-kernel-WYBhQW\\node_modules\\@aws-cdk\\asset-kubectl-v20\\layer'
}
```

Comment: May be Try to remove node_modules directory if you have one and run cdk deploy again. `npm remove node_modules`. `npm remove package-lock.json`.

Comment: remove it from where..?

Comment: You can see the path in the error message.

Comment: @ArpitJain This is a temp folder, a new one is created every time 'cdk deploy' is run, so deleting it has no effect.

Comment: Did you try it as it seems from the error message that it failed to run `rmdir` because folder is not empty.

Comment: @ArpitJain Yes. It creates a new 'jsii-kernel-****' folder and shows the error for the new folder.